# How many Development cards can a player play on their turn?

Tags: catan

Is there a limit to the number of development cards one can play on their turn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Catan rules, you can only play one (1) development card on your turn.

> You may build roads, settlements or cities and/or buy development
>   cards. You may also play one development card at any time during your
>   turn.

[Catan Rules](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_5th_ed_rules_eng_150303.pdf)

Comment: This pertains to Knight or Progress cards.  There is an exception for Victory Points.

Comment: @LeppyR64 : The question is about "Development Cards". There are NO development cards in Catan Cities and Knights. From the rules, there are «6 “Defender of Catan” Victory Point Cards. Each VP Card is worth 1 VP and is placed face up in front of the player... Victory Point Cards must be played immediately when
drawn. »
https://www.catan.com/down/?/files/downloads/catan_ck_5th_ed_rules_150303.pdf

Comment: From the link you posted "You may only play 1 development card during your turn—
either 1 knight card or 1 progress card. You can play the
card at any time, even before you roll the dice. You may not,
however, play a card that you bought during the same turn.
Exception: If you buy a card and 
it is a victory point card Y that 
brings you to 10 points, you may 
immediately reveal this card 
(and all other VP cards) and 
win the game.
You only reveal victory point
cards when the game is over—once
you or an opponent reaches 10+
victory points and declares victory."

Comment: @LeppyR64 : As I illustrated in response to your first comment, the OP's question was clearly about "Catan", and not about "Catan Cities & Knights". Therefore, this discussion is off-topic and I suggest that you post another question if you want to get answers concerning "Catan Cities & Knights"

Comment: @RobertMiller There may be some confusion here because later editions of Catan renamed “soldiers cards to “knight” cards. A terrible choice IMO since “knight” already has a different meaning in Catan. But “progress” and “knight” are 2 different types/categories of development cards.

Comment: Note that VP cards are not ever played. You simply always have the VP the moment you buy the card. You simply reveal them when you reach 10 total points. You don’t play them.

Comment: @RobertMiller Leppy's comments do not refer to Cities and Knights rules, you have become confused. Leppy is correct, in base Catan, multiple VP development cards may be 'revealed' in one turn to win the game - though these are not technically 'played' at all - so it's kind of tangential to the question